# Calling default constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a problem with a default constructor in C++.  It's a simple thing but can't see what's wrong with it.

I have a constructor with 3 optional parameters, with const values on initialization list:

```
data::data(int D = 1, int M = 1, int Y = 1583) : Day(D), Month(M), Year(Y)  
{  
    if (!CorrectDate()) throw "Wrong Date!";  
}
```

Why can I call it with one, two or three parameters and it works just fine but doesn't when I call it with no parameters?

```
data tommorrow();
```

Comment: See: [Most vexing parse: why doesn't A a(()); work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work).  The short answer is, you are declaring a function there.  If you want to call the default constructor, leave out the parens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data tomorrow();` is a declaration of a function that returns a `data` and takes no parameters.  To create a `data` object with no explicit constructor arguments, just do `data tomorrow;` without the parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

Define it as

```
data tomorrow;
```

`data tomorrow();` is the same as defining a function called `tomorrow` which returns `data`

Answer (score 1):

You are probably doing something like

```
data something();
```

which is not an initialization of a variable of type `data` called `something`, but the declaration of a function called `something` that returns `data`.

If this is the case, the correct would be:

```
data something;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a function which returns a data, you can do either:

```
data tommorow;
```

Without (), or you can do:

```
data tommorow = data();
```